# MIN and SUM functions in Google Sheets for Time

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I'm trying to use the MIN and SUM function but the answer always comes back with either `0`, `ERROR` or `!DIV/0`.

The format I want to have for my times are for example: 0.03, 10.56, 1:13.00.

`=MIN` example:

[image]

`=SUM` example:

[image]

One final thing I would want is that the last digit can only be 0, 3 or 6.
So for example 1.03 + 1.06 + 1.03 = 3.13 and not 3.12.

Please help, I've been trying to solve this for days.

Comment: Sorry, it is mm:ss.ms

Comment: you getting `0`, `ERROR` or `!DIV/0` because you are trying to calculate text format with number format. its same like if you would try to sum `ten+10` and expect `20`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **first, you need to do is to change your input by entering it like `0:0:10.13` which will output as `00:10.13` if you will follow steps from image and custom format your column:**

[image: 1]

---

- **then you can sum it up with formula `=SUM(A8+B10+D7)`:**

[image: 1]

---

- **lastly, to cover the last digit change you can use simple `IF()` to convert it based on logic rules:**


  ```
  =IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(C13, 1))>0, VALUE(RIGHT(C13, 1))<3),  LEFT(C13,7)&0,
   IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(C13, 1))>3, VALUE(RIGHT(C13, 1))<6),  LEFT(C13,7)&3,
   IF(AND(VALUE(RIGHT(C13, 1))>6, VALUE(RIGHT(C13, 1))<10), LEFT(C13,7)&6, C13)))
  ```

[image: 2]

Comment: I applied the new time format "Minute (01) : Second (01) . Milliseconds (01)" to column A. Wrote the times in A1 to A3. gave A4 a function of "=SUM(A1+A2+A3)" and I get: https://i.gyazo.com/5d3163cf893e1ff0b5e6e1cdc97c30a0.png

Comment: If I change the ":" into a "." in both the cells and in the format it all works. lol

Comment: Think I got it to work now. was a bit confused about your first sentence about typing one thing and it will display in another. 
Thank you so much <3

Comment: @user207079 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MWHJUtyz3ITP1IOrc3YQrqhi8FfnvXZg7IYxncd5yVQ/edit?usp=sharing